# trying to run tensorboard (for pytorch, on windows) results in AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: pytorch, conda, environment, tensorboard, h5py

seems like it might be a build issue but it still occurs after i build the environment from scratch.

important notes: i'm working in a windows environment, and not using tensorflow, but pytorch and tensorboard.

i tried conda install h5py but the conda list still shows the old version.

here's the conda list output

```
# packages in environment at D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_new:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.15.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.7.4.post0      py38h294d835_1    conda-forge
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             3.0.1            py38haa95532_0
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h294d835_1003    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.10.14                    0    anaconda
cached-property           1.5.2                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cached_property           1.5.2              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.6.20                py38_0    anaconda
cffi                      1.15.0           py38hd8c33c5_0    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0            py38haa244fe_2    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        2.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.0.3            py38haa244fe_1    conda-forge
cloudpickle               2.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
coverage                  6.1.1            py38h294d835_1    conda-forge
cryptography              35.0.0           py38hb7941b4_2    conda-forge
cudatoolkit               10.2.89              hb195166_9    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cython                    0.29.24          py38h885f38d_1    conda-forge
cytoolz                   0.11.2           py38h294d835_1    conda-forge
dask-core                 2021.11.0          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dataclasses               0.8                pyhc8e2a94_3    conda-forge
dill                      0.3.2                      py_0    anaconda
enum34                    1.1.10           py38h32f6830_2    conda-forge
filelock                  3.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               hd328e21_0
fsspec                    2021.11.0          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
geos                      3.10.0               h39d44d4_0    conda-forge
google-auth               1.35.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.36.1           py38hc60d5dd_1
h5py                      2.10.0           py38h5e291fa_0    anaconda
hdf5                      1.10.4          nompi_hcc15c50_1106    conda-forge
huggingface_hub           0.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1    anaconda
icu                       58.2             vc14hc45fdbb_0  [vc14]  anaconda
idna                      3.1                pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
imagecodecs-lite          2019.12.3        py38h347fdf6_3    conda-forge
imageio                   2.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
imgaug                    0.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        4.8.1            py38haa244fe_1    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        4.8.1                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          haa95532_3556
joblib                    0.17.0                     py_0    anaconda
jpeg                      9b               vc14h4d7706e_1  [vc14]  anaconda
kiwisolver                1.3.2            py38hbd9d945_1    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.2               h20d022d_3    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.79.1               h789b8ee_1    conda-forge
libopencv                 4.0.1                hbb9e17c_0
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf               3.17.2               h23ce68f_1
libssh2                   1.10.0               h680486a_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.2.0                hd0e1b90_0
libuv                     1.40.0               he774522_0
libwebp                   1.2.0                h2bbff1b_0
locket                    0.2.0                      py_2    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_1
markdown                  3.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.4.3            py38haa244fe_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.4.3            py38h1f000d6_1    conda-forge
mkl                       2021.4.0           haa95532_640
mkl-service               2.4.0            py38h2bbff1b_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py38h277e83a_0
mkl_random                1.2.2            py38hf11a4ad_0
multicore-tsne            0.1_d4ff4aab     py38h2f20550_1    conda-forge
multidict                 5.2.0            py38h294d835_1    conda-forge
networkx                  2.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
nibabel                   3.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.21.2           py38hfca59bb_0
numpy-base                1.21.2           py38h0829f74_0
oauthlib                  3.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46               pyhd3eb1b0_0
opencv                    4.0.1            py38h2a7c758_0
openssl                   1.1.1l               h2bbff1b_0
packaging                 21.0               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.1.3            py38ha925a31_0    anaconda
partd                     1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pathlib                   1.0.1            py38haa244fe_5    conda-forge
pillow                    8.4.0            py38hd45dc43_0
pip                       20.2.4                   py38_0    anaconda
pooch                     1.5.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.17.2           py38hd77b12b_0
py-opencv                 4.0.1            py38he44ac1e_0
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1-modules            0.2.7                      py_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pydicom                   2.2.2              pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
pyjwt                     2.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 21.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38ha925a31_4    anaconda
pyreadline                2.1             py38haa244fe_1005    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38haa244fe_4    conda-forge
python                    3.8.5                h5fd99cc_1    anaconda
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      2_cp38    conda-forge
pytorch                   1.10.0          py3.8_cuda10.2_cudnn7_0    pytorch
pytorch-metric-learning   0.9.99             pyh39e3cac_0    metric-learning
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0    anaconda
pyu2f                     0.1.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pywavelets                1.1.1            py38h6f4d8f0_4    conda-forge
pyyaml                    3.13             py38hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0  [vc14]  anaconda
regex                     2021.11.2        py38h294d835_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.26.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
rsa                       4.7.2              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
sacremoses                0.0.46             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
scikit-image              0.18.3           py38h5d928e2_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              0.23.2           py38h47e9c7a_0    anaconda
scipy                     1.7.1            py38hbe87c03_2
setuptools                50.3.0           py38h9490d1a_1    anaconda
shapely                   1.8.0            py38he21f6c5_1    conda-forge
sip                       4.19.25          py38h885f38d_1    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
sqlite                    3.33.0               h2a8f88b_0    anaconda
tensorboard               2.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.0            py38haa244fe_1    conda-forge
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             2.1.0              pyh5ca1d4c_0    anaconda
tifffile                  2019.7.26.2              py38_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.11               h2bbff1b_0
tokenizers                0.10.3           py38h291c280_1    conda-forge
tomli                     1.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
toolz                     0.11.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
torchaudio                0.10.0               py38_cu102    pytorch
torchvision               0.11.1               py38_cu102    pytorch
tornado                   6.1              py38h294d835_2    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.62.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
transformers              4.12.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         3.10.0.2             hd3eb1b0_0
typing_extensions         3.10.0.2           pyh06a4308_0
urllib3                   1.26.7             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4    anaconda
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_3    anaconda
werkzeug                  2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.35.1                     py_0    anaconda
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py38haa244fe_3    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                      py38_0    anaconda
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
yaml                      0.1.7            vc14h4cb57cf_1  [vc14]  anaconda
yarl                      1.7.2            py38h294d835_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11           vc14h1cdd9ab_1  [vc14]  anaconda
zstd                      1.4.9                h19a0ad4_0
```

and the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/env_zoo/Lib/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.beholder import beholder_plugin_loader
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\beholder\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib as feature_column
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column_lib.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column import *
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 147, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.layers import base
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers import base
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\activations.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import advanced_activations
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing.image_preprocessing import CenterCrop
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\preprocessing\image_preprocessing.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing import image as image_preprocessing
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import all_utils as utils
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\all_utils.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training import Model
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 53, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.saving import save
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 30, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import version
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\h5py\version.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import h5 as _h5
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "h5py\h5.pyx", line 41, in init h5py.h5
AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

i only try to start tensorboard and get this message.

**if there is something wrong with the way i post my question, please give constructive feedback.**

Comment: Any specific reason to build it from scratch?

Comment: i suspected there are dependency issues so i created a new conda env and tried to pinpoint the faulty package by installing each package separately. it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorboard is now a part of pytorch itself([link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-use-tensorboard-with-pytorch/61852/2))

Just import the following

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
```

For the variables you want to track on tensorboard, in the code add the following

```
var = <value_you_want_to_track>
writer.add_scalar('<variable_name>',var,epoch)
```

and once you have your tensorboard variables defined in the code, in your main.py , you can write the following

```
writer = SummaryWriter(path_of_runs_folder)
```

Edit 1: Since OP wanted a way to install tensorboard without handling individual dependencies, I have created YAML file which you can use in your machine to set up the environment.

save the following block of code as env.yml

```
name: pytorch_tensorboard
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_gnu
  - absl-py=0.15.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - aiohttp=3.7.4.post0=py38h497a2fe_0
  - async-timeout=3.0.1=py38h06a4308_0
  - attrs=21.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - blinker=1.4=py_1
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py38h497a2fe_1001
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
  - c-ares=1.17.1=h27cfd23_0
  - ca-certificates=2021.10.8=ha878542_0
  - cachetools=4.2.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - certifi=2021.10.8=py38h578d9bd_1
  - cffi=1.14.6=py38h400218f_0
  - chardet=4.0.0=py38h578d9bd_2
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - click=8.0.3=py38h578d9bd_1
  - cryptography=35.0.0=py38ha5dfef3_0
  - cudatoolkit=10.2.89=hfd86e86_1
  - dataclasses=0.8=pyhc8e2a94_3
  - ffmpeg=4.3=hf484d3e_0
  - freetype=2.11.0=h70c0345_0
  - giflib=5.2.1=h7b6447c_0
  - gmp=6.2.1=h2531618_2
  - gnutls=3.6.15=he1e5248_0
  - google-auth=1.35.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - google-auth-oauthlib=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - grpcio=1.37.1=py38hdd6454d_0
  - idna=3.1=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - importlib-metadata=4.8.2=py38h578d9bd_0
  - intel-openmp=2021.4.0=h06a4308_3561
  - jpeg=9d=h7f8727e_0
  - lame=3.100=h7b6447c_0
  - lcms2=2.12=h3be6417_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=h7274673_9
  - libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
  - libgcc-ng=9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - libgomp=9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - libiconv=1.15=h63c8f33_5
  - libidn2=2.3.2=h7f8727e_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - libprotobuf=3.15.8=h780b84a_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.3.0=hd4cf53a_17
  - libtasn1=4.16.0=h27cfd23_0
  - libtiff=4.2.0=h85742a9_0
  - libunistring=0.9.10=h27cfd23_0
  - libuv=1.40.0=h7b6447c_0
  - libwebp=1.2.0=h89dd481_0
  - libwebp-base=1.2.0=h27cfd23_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.3=h295c915_1
  - markdown=3.3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mkl=2021.4.0=h06a4308_640
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py38h7f8727e_0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.1=py38hd3c417c_0
  - mkl_random=1.2.2=py38h51133e4_0
  - multidict=5.1.0=py38h27cfd23_2
  - ncurses=6.3=heee7806_1
  - nettle=3.7.3=hbbd107a_1
  - numpy=1.21.2=py38h20f2e39_0
  - numpy-base=1.21.2=py38h79a1101_0
  - oauthlib=3.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - olefile=0.46=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - openh264=2.1.0=hd408876_0
  - openssl=1.1.1l=h7f8727e_0
  - pillow=8.4.0=py38h5aabda8_0
  - pip=21.2.4=py38h06a4308_0
  - protobuf=3.15.8=py38h709712a_0
  - pyasn1=0.4.8=py_0
  - pyasn1-modules=0.2.7=py_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyjwt=2.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyopenssl=21.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py38h578d9bd_4
  - python=3.8.5=h7579374_1
  - python_abi=3.8=2_cp38
  - pytorch=1.10.0=py3.8_cuda10.2_cudnn7.6.5_0
  - pytorch-mutex=1.0=cuda
  - pyu2f=0.1.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - readline=8.1=h27cfd23_0
  - requests=2.26.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - requests-oauthlib=1.3.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - rsa=4.7.2=pyh44b312d_0
  - setuptools=58.0.4=py38h06a4308_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sqlite=3.36.0=hc218d9a_0
  - tensorboard=2.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - tensorboard-data-server=0.6.0=py38h2b97feb_0
  - tensorboard-plugin-wit=1.8.0=pyh44b312d_0
  - tk=8.6.11=h1ccaba5_0
  - torchaudio=0.10.0=py38_cu102
  - torchvision=0.11.1=py38_cu102
  - typing-extensions=3.10.0.2=hd3eb1b0_0
  - typing_extensions=3.10.0.2=pyh06a4308_0
  - tzdata=2021e=hda174b7_0
  - urllib3=1.26.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - werkzeug=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wheel=0.37.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - yarl=1.6.3=py38h497a2fe_2
  - zipp=3.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.4.9=haebb681_0
```

now run the following command in the directory you saved the above file

```
conda env create --file env.yml
```

This will set up Pytorch 1.10 with cuda, Python 3.8.5 and Tensorboard onto the environment, you dont need to do it manually for each dependencies.

environment will be created by name of "pytorch_tensorboard". You can change that by modifying the 1st line of env.yml

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. in the pytorch tensorboard tutorial it is shown you are still required to install tensorboard. the error message i receive when i try to run the 'main' from tensorboard package.

Comment: @enter_thevoid have a look at the Edit 1. Doing those steps can solve your issue. 
lmk about it

Comment: couldn't use the yml file you sent, got a ResolvePackageNotFound error.

Comment: Can you show the error , what packages are not available as such on your side as per the error and their versions

Comment: Ah yes(https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7311#issuecomment-442320274), Mine is linux, and yours is windows, the export might fail due to that. Let me create similar env in windows and update the answer